# Bokashi with little food waste

Tags: compost

I am new to composting and I have so far failed 2 batches of bokashi. I have a 20l bokashi bin which lasted about 3 weeks in my 2 attempts before they started to smell rotten. It usually takes me about 2-3 days to accumulate enough food scraps (in a small bowl) to add to the bin. During the period, the food scraps stay in the fridge uncovered.

In retrospective, here are the things I know I should be doing in my next attempt:

- Compress food scrap after adding bokashi
- Check bokashi juice more frequently at the beginning even when there is no liquid for a while
- Use more bokashi?

**What I still can’t find answers for and need your help with:**

- Should I add food scraps more often instead of leaving them in the fridge where they may grow bad mold?
- If I do it correctly and it doesn’t rot, can I keep adding food scraps until the bin is full (probably in 3-4 months), or should I empty it more often?
- Should the bin be absolutely air tight? When it started to rot, I can come close and smell the odour through a tiny air gap near the lid.
- When it starts to rot, can it be saved with more bokashi or do I have to start over?
- How is burying food crap directly into the garden any different? (Perhaps the smell?)

Thanks in advance!